# C macro to unroll fixed sized array declaration, rename each with index suffix

Tags: c

Is it possible to define a macro `INPUT_ARR`, so that `int a[4]; void (INPUT_ARR(int, a, 4)){}` equals to `void (int a0, int a1, int a2, int a3){}`

Comment: Might as well point it out, C is not C++, please don't spam tags.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because you can't use a loop inside a macro.

Comment: Also this expansion leads to a syntax error - maybe you meant to hav ea function name in there somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#define INPUT_ARR(type, name, count) IARR ## count (type, name)

#define IARR0(type, name)
#define IARR1(type, name) type name##0
#define IARR2(type, name) IARR1(type, name), type name##1
#define IARR3(type, name) IARR2(type, name), type name##2
#define IARR4(type, name) IARR3(type, name), type name##3

void func (INPUT_ARR(int, a, 4)){}

int main()
{
    func(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Results of `gcc -E` (excluding `main`):

```
void func (int a0, int a1, int a2, int a3){}
```

You'll need to add IARR lines up until the max count that you want to support. It's not possible to have recursive macro definitions that go on automatically.

Comment: *"It's not possible to have recursive macro definitions that go on automatically."*. Then you need to generate an "iarr.h" file with a script and include it ;-)